# 404 when GETing from STATIC_URL does not call GET on my fallback View

Tags: django, django-urls, whitenoise

In my `settings.py`, I have `STATIC_URL='/static/'`

I have a view which I use as a fallback for the static url

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(request):
        return XXX
```

which I add it to my urls like so

```
urlpatterns += [url(r'^/static/', MyView.as_view())]
```

Next, I want to make sure that the fallback URL is working. When I go to a bad link like `localhost/static/garbage` it shows me the Django 404 error page but it claims that it was raised by `MyView`.

What's extremely frustrating is I have two apps with the same static files handling. One of the apps trigger my view, the other does not. I cannot tell what's different that's causing the issue. Both are on `whitenoise==4.1.x` and `django==2.3`

Answer (score 0):

Run under wsgi instead of `runserver`.

For some reason when using runserver, Django has a different static assets routing logic where MyView is bypassed and I get a different 404 page. When I switch to gunicorn everything works fine.